# How to create C# dynamic object?

Tags: c#, linq, object, dynamic

In C#, I need to create a function that returns an object which may possibly consist of:

```
{ itemID: "A1", itemDesc: "apple" }
```

OR

```
{ groupID: "G1", groupDesc: "group1" } ..etc

// Please don't be concerned about why don't create another function for this,
// or why don't consider 'ID' instead.
```

I am curious. The reason, this is straightforward in javascript, as you can assign any key to an object without pre-defining it.

However, when it comes to C#, I am puzzled.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**

Sorry I should have stated by question clearer (so it may not be that 'duplicated')

My function actually returns a Class, as below:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public int myKey {get;set;}
    public List<customClass> listRecord {get;set;}
}
```

The `customClass` is the dynamic "Object" that I refer to.
Note that the records are queried from the LINQ.

Thanks for the suggestions, but I seem not able to do this:

```
var result = (from a in db.MyTable
              select new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject()
              {
                 ....
```

Neither I can `select new dynamic`

Comment: objects in javascript are actually closer to [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)s in C#. Depending on usage, it may be more appropriate to return a Dictionary here. Or, don't try to write javascript in C#.

Comment: The marked duplicate is the literal answer to your question. But I agree with @Damien that usage here may be better served using a dictionary. Of course, your question lacks much detail, so it's impossible to say what in your case would work best.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I have edited my question. I don't think this is considered 'Duplicated' as there are differences. But ya. as Damien mentioned, i would test using Dictionary

Comment: _"I seem not able to do this"_ -- you need to be more specific. This question is likely a lost cause. The question you originally asked isn't actually the question you wanted an answer to. You need to post a new question in which you present your question clearly. Make sure you include in that post a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, and explain what that code does and what you want instead. Be sure to address why neither using a dictionary and `ExpandoObject` work for you, _with specific details_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I only mentioned ExpandoObject doesn't work, but not yet tested Dictionary.

Comment: I'm assuming you'll have the wisdom to not post the question if dictionary suits your needs. So my advice assumes that neither works, and in that case your question would need to include good explanations for the reasons each doesn't work.

Comment: Peter I don't understand your assumption. But here the Dictionary is the solution that works for me. So i don't considered this as a duplicate (after having the question edited). Credit to @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 8):

You may need ExpandoObject class:

```
dynamic temp = new ExpandoObject();
temp.member1= "aha";
temp.member2= 1234;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Anonymous class can't be changed once defined.ExpandoObject is closer to javascript object.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic typing C# has a `dynamic` keyword, but it is strongly recommended not to use dynamic typing. Static typing allows you to check type on compilation and fail fast.

```
public dynamic Func()
{
    return new { itemID = "A1", itemDesc = "apple" };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with dynamic keyword:

```
public dynamic GetMyObject()
{
    return new { X= "X", Y= "Y" };
}
```

and You can use it with

```
dynamic myObject=GetMyObject();
myObject.X;
myObject.Y;
```